# Landscape & Float & Text & minipage

Tags: floats, subfloats, tabularx, minipage, landscape

Writing a landscape manual with subsection on the top, with images on the left using figures. On the right is the list of text. I have issues trying to have them on the same page when I use the minipage function. The intended format would be all the figures occupying half of the landscape page and the list on the other half using minipage. Would be greatly appreciated if someone could guide me to the right direction to fix this or using another method.[image][image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[a4paper, includeheadfoot]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx, wrapfig, subcaption, setspace, booktabs}
\usepackage{lscape}


\begin{document}

%A whole bunch of other pages

\newgeometry{left=1cm, right = 1cm , top = 1.5cm, bottom= 0.5cm}

\subsection{Operating Procedure with Pictures}

\begin{figure}[ht]

     \begin{subfigure}{0.25\linewidth}
     \includegraphics[width= 6cm]{Steps/SiloStep.jpg}
     \caption{Main Silo}
     \end{subfigure}
     \begin{subfigure}{0.25\linewidth}
     \includegraphics[width = 6cm]{Steps/SmallDisplayMarked.jpg}
     \caption{Display}
     \end{subfigure}
     \vspace{0.2cm}

     \begin{subfigure}{0.25\linewidth}
     \includegraphics[width = 6cm]{Steps/MixerStep.jpg}
     \caption{Mixer}
     \end{subfigure}
     \begin{subfigure}{0.25\linewidth}
     \includegraphics[width = 6cm]{Steps/PackingStep.jpg}
     \caption{Packing Machine}
     \end{subfigure}
     \vspace{0.2cm}

     \begin{subfigure}{0.25\linewidth}
     \includegraphics[width = 6cm]{Steps/BTStep.jpg}
     \caption{Bottom Right}
     \end{subfigure}

\end{figure}

\hfill

\begin{minipage}[b]{0.5\textwidth}

\begin{tabular}{|p{0.95\textwidth}}

\begin{enumerate}
\setcounter{enumi}{4}

%\item all the items
\end{enumerate}

\end{tabular}
\end{minipage}

\end{landscape}

\clearpage
\restoregeometry
```

Comment: Hi, Have you tried placing the figure inside a minipage as well? `\begin{minipage}[b]{0.5\textwidth} \begin{figure} ... \end{figure}\end{minipage}`

Comment: Yeah I tried that but minipage function cannot work with the error: not in outer par mode.

Comment: Ok, so I actually managed to get the floats and the text to line side by side but now I couldn't figure out why the subsection would not fit into the same page. 
What I changed in my code was putting` \begin{minipage}` inside the \begin`{figure}...\end{figure}` function. So it looks like this:

`\begin{figure}[ht]
\begin{minipage}{0.8\textwidth}
\begin{subfigure}
.
\end{subfigure}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}
%same stuff in the middle
\end{minipage}
\end{figure}`

I tried expanding the geometry on the left and right but it doesn't seem to be working for the subsection to fit